# Three.js BVHLoader in React/React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, three.js, 3d

I am trying to make an application and/or website where BVH animation is displayed. I found the example in Three.js: [BVHLoader example](https://github.com/rollup/three-jsnext/blob/master/examples/webgl_loader_bvh.html). I also know it is possible to use React and React Native with Three.js. However, I am unable to replicate this particular example in React in any way. Is there a straightforward way to transform this code to React and eventually React Native?

Answer (score 0):

You can use React Three Fiber for utilize React with ThreeJS:

```
import { BVHLoader } from "three/examples/jsm/loaders/BVHLoader";
import { FBXLoader } from "three/examples/jsm/loaders/FBXLoader";
export const Model = () => {
  const model = useLoader(FBXLoader, "/model.fbx");
  let animLoader = new BVHLoader();
  animLoader.load("/anim.bvh", function (result) {
    let m = new THREE.AnimationMixer(model);
    m.clipAction(result.clip).play();
  });
  return <primitive object={model} />;
};
```